# Actionscript swiping gesture difficulty

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I am still fairly new to actionscript and have been puzzled for a few days about implementing the swiping gesture. 
I'm making a game similar to fruit ninja where the user swipes incoming objects, I've been trying to figure out how to make an object fall down off the screen after swiping it.

```
        import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;


    //haggis movement
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);

    function gameloop(e:Event):void {
        haggis.x=70;
        if (haggis.x<-130) 
    {
            haggis.x=1200;
        }
    }

    //Swipe Gesture

    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
    stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe); 
    function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    if (e.offsetX == 1) {
        //User swiped towards right
        haggis.y += 200;
    }
    if (e.offsetX == -1) {
    //User swiped towards left
    haggis.y += 200;
    } 
    if (e.offsetY == 1) {
    //User swiped towards bottom
    haggis.y += 200;
    }
    if (e.offsetY == -1) {
    //User swiped towards top
    haggis.y += 200;
    } 
    }


//piper hit by haggis

piper.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, piper_damaged);
    function piper_damaged(event:Event):void {
        if (piper.hitTestObject(haggis)) {
            piper.gotoAndPlay(2);
                    }

    }
```

haggis is the object to be swiped by the user.

I am also trying to figure out how to make the haggis reset back to its original position after falling off the screen, any help about this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add an increment to haggis.y in your game loop, ie:

```
haggis.y ++;
```

If you want to simulate gravity increment a yMomemtum variable and add THAT to haggis.y;
If you want the haggis to fall ONLY once you've swiped it, add a haggisSwiped:Boolean and set it true when the player swipes. Then, in your game loop, check:

```
if (haggisSwiped) {
    haggis.y ++;
}
```

Also, you set haggis.x to 70 at every frame and immediately check if it's less than -130. Do you know why, because I can't tell.